# onGroupClick not working in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have developed the sample code of ExpandableListView in Android. Data is being populated in Adapter and displaying in the ExpandableListView properly. but i am facing one severe issue of not expanding child view after tapping on Groupview. i have checked links on google and followed each steps properly however, it is not expanded.

I have overridden onGroupClick event that you can find below and it always returns false, however, child views are not coming on tapping on groupview. Please assist. child view are populated and even displayed in ExpandableListView that i have confirmed with small code but it is not working with "OnGroupClick".

```
        @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 /* parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
        if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
            parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        else
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
 */         
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: All your code is commented out... so this will indeed always return false.

Comment: check your child count that not equal to zero

Comment: I have checked child count and it always return not equal to zero values. to double check, i have used expandGroup method with object of Expandablelistview and it shows all child views open.